# Inheriting a List<> in c# and overriding the constructor

Tags: c#, list, constructor, subclass

I'm trying to create a wrapper around List to do some specific things I want, such as compute max min, extract specific values from some elements, etc.

I start with

```
    public struct datum {
      public UInt32[] chan;
      public UInt64 sample_number;
      public UInt32 time;
      public UInt32 source_sector;
    } 

    public class dataSet : List<datum> {
     bool dirty=true;
     ....
    }
```

the methods are typically like this (I want to know if the list has been modified as I have a max()/min() function that only parses the data when it has been modified and caches the values to reuse if the List has not been modified)

```
     public new void Add(datum x ) {
        base.Add(x);
        this.dirty = true;
    }
```

However, I'm not sure how to create a constructor.   This syntax does not work.. how can I get this type of behavior?

```
    public dataSet(int count) {
        this = (dataSet) new List<datum>(count);
    }
```

I also have this constructor, which seems to work fine (no compilation errors) though untested

```
    public dataSet(List<datum> data) {
        this.AddRange(data);
    }
```

I came across a post that said that you should use a Collection and a List is used for speed. Though I need the speed, and I'm not sure why a Collection would be better?

--UPDATE--

I don't want to use linq as you can't create something that computes max/min simultaneously as efficiently as this:

```
    public void recalculateMaxMin() {
        foreach (var d in data) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                if (d.chan[i] > max[i]) max[i] = d.chan[i];
                if (d.chan[i] < min[i]) min[i] = d.chan[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never ever set `"this"` to something in C#. I think you are looking for this:

```
public dataSet(int count)
     : base(count)
{ }
```

However in my opinion you should take a look at `"System.Linq"` namespace. I think what you are trying to implement has been done before by Microsoft. 'Select', 'Join', 'Where' and many other clauses has been already implemented in Linq. Also you can use `"INotifyCollectionChanged"` interface to implement the dirty thing.

Here are some references:

1. [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx)
2. [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397897.aspx)

If you realy need to implement a complete List class with a new behavior, implementing `"System.Collections.Generic.IList"` interface is the only thing that will rock your idea in an advanced and perfect way. It's more customizable than inheriting from the List class and trying to change everything you have no access to.

Hope it helps

Cheers

Comment: I've not been able to find any examples of INotifyCollectionChanged and a List<> -- can you point me to one or provide one?  That would be an ideal implementaiton

Comment: My dear, take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42536/List-vs-ObservableCollection-vs-INotifyPropertyCha

Comment: INotifyCollectionChanged is an interface that has an event named "CollectionChanged". ObservableCollection<T> has already implemented the interface. You should just simply use it. Have fun. ;)

Comment: @mahammad I'm sorry, my skills at using notifications are weak and the examples aren't helping me.  do I do something like bool dirty {
            get {return _dirty;}
            set {_dirty = false; onPropertyChanged(this, "dirty"); }
        }  and this syntax doesn't work : public class DatumSet : List<datum>, INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: instead of inheriting from List<datum>, inherit from ObservableCollection<datum> and handle the CollectionChanged event. If will fire whenever something changes the collection instance. Got it Reza?

Comment: How is it going @reza? Where are you so far? :)

Answer (score 7):

> I'm trying to create a wrapper around List to do some specific things I want, such as compute max min, extract specific values from some elements, etc.

Don't. Just use LINQ to Objects. That's what it was *designed* for:

```
var list = new List<int> { 10, 20, 30 };
var average = list.Average();
var max = list.Max();
// etc
```

In general, I would advise against deriving from `List<T>` anyway - that's not what it was designed for. However, if you must, you just chain from one constructor to a base constructor:

```
public dataSet(int count) : base(count)
{
    // Add in any extra code you want to here. Probably none in this case.
    // It would execute *after* the base constructor call.
}
```

See my [article on constructors](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html) for more information about constructor chaining.

(I'd also *strongly* advise you to change the name - `dataSet` doesn't comply with .NET naming conventions, and `DataSet` would mean [something else entirely](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) to most .NET developers.)

Comment: It is not a list<int>, it is a list<datum> and thus Max() Average() does not apply. `UInt32[] chan`  is 16 wide, and I am computing the max for each of the entries among all others (i.e. max of index 1 across all entries, max of index 2 across all entries, etc).  You can't use standard linq and I've looked at a couple linq extensions to allow for this sort of query, but it is not as speed efficient for my purposes.

Comment: @reza: `Max` would apply if you make `Datum` implement `IComparable<T>`. `Average` is more of a pain, but you can easily write your own extension method for it. Heck, you can write your own extension methods for all of these things - nothing you've said so far suggests you really need your own collection type.

Comment: the main issue is that I would have to create a separate max and min, each having to itterate through the data set.  My implemenation (see above) itterates through it just once to compute both.  That's the main reason I didn't go with linq.

Answer (score 1):

```
public dataSet(int count) 
    : base(count)  {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the base type's constructor using `base()`

```
public dataSet(int count) : base(count) 
{  
    // no need to implement anything here. base(count) will call the base
    // type's constructor
}
```